# How to change value of specify attribute of EDI (840) file using BizTalk 2010

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, edi

I have a BizTalk application receive 840 EDI file and send to downstream through HTTP with bidirectional pipeline:AS2SEND and AS2RECEIVE, `OrderID` is in received in the EDI file, now I want get the `OrderID` from the response, but it seems to be impossible. I noticed that the `MessageID` can be sent back as original, so I want to "rename" the `MessageID` to put `OrderID` in the MessageID so that I can figure out whether what I sent to downstream (with the specify order) has been sent and received successfully. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a Two-Way Port, you can manage the process in an Orchestration.  That way, you don't have to worry about matching the request and responses yourself.

Comment: The EDI project is in a encrypted format, and we don't have any orchestration at all. What we do is just receiving EDI files from upstream and transforming to xml  with the help of biztalk, then send to downstream and downsteam will return a MDN response. How can I make the MDN response with our "OrderID" included?

Comment: Well, any encryption and an Orchestration aren't really related.  While you don't have to use an Orchestration, it is definitely the easiest way to manage the Two-Way Operation.  As for the content of the MDN, that's up to the receiver (downstream system).

Answer (score 0):

It is not suggested to replace the messageID.

Could you provide more detail on how that happen: ""OrderID" is in received the EDI file" but you cannot  get the "OrderID" from the response?

Is the response from your downstream?

Comment: No, I mean I get EDI file from upstream which with "OrderID" included, and then I send it thorugh biztalk, the downstream will return a response to tell me that they have received the file successsfully, but they often told us some Order is not received by them, what we get from included nothing to help figure out which order it is.To put it simply, we send them an order but we can't make sure the order is recieved by them from the response they returned.

Comment: So, BizTalk application here just give you "file level" response here, but what you expected is "order level".